# php header output image sometimes not work while multiple image loading

Tags: php, image, apache, web, config

I load multiple image by php header output image/png, but there is always an image not displaying when I refresh page per time: sometimes it's the first image that does not load successfully, sometimes it's the last image.

the `error_log` showed:

> PHP Warning:  imagecreatefromjpeg(): gd-jpeg: JPEG library reports unrecoverable error:....Insufficient memory (case 4)
>
> PHP Warning:  imagecreatefromjpeg(): .... is not a valid JPEG file

index.html

```
<img src="/pad.php/upload/190004-1">
<img src="/pad.php/upload/190004-2">
<img src="/pad.php/upload/190004-3">
<img src="/pad.php/upload/190004-1">
```

the pad.php I using is from https://github.com/stuporglue/sstiles
this php is using for map tiles,but the map did not display all image tiles,
so I found sometimes image not show, but when I copy the image url to new tab,
it shows successfully.

I tried `ini_set("memory_limit","-1")` but is not working

[[image: here is the speed from the file]]

Comment: post some code please

Comment: That "insufficient memory" does not suggest it's a header problem...